# Using 'caveats' in context of problems

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am using the world *caveats* as follows:

*However, there are three major caveats in using these data sets.*

The meaning - there are 3 major *drawbacks/flaws* that a researcher might encounter if he or she uses these data sets.

However, this is where I am confused. My internal meaning of the statement is: *well these data sets are good, and people use them but in using them, they also tend to overlook these flaws that are inherent to them and that will propagate in the research they do if the use this data set.*

Is my usage correct? Are there any more prudent words that fit the context better? The setting of the document is strictly academic.

Comment: caveat is OK, but it means warning (beware), not drawback or flaw. Proviso also would work.

Comment: @Lambie thanks! can you please use proviso in a sentence that means the same?

Comment: _Caveat_ would mean "issue you need to be aware of", which could apply to drawbacks/flaws that are not necessarily a problem. They could be, which is why you need to look out, but there is a chance nothing bad will happen even if you don't. They are more like pieces of advice to prevent mistakes/faults.